# SonarQube SaaS Integration in TFS 2012 Xaml

Tags: sonarqube, saas

Is there a way to use TFS 2012 xaml and configure it to call SonarQube using a URL instead of an EXE file?
The reason I have a URL is because I use SonarQube in Azure with VSTS but I need to support our old TFS as well.

The URL I have looks like this : http://localhost:9000

Thanks!

Comment: Why not importing the whole project in Visual Studio Team Services and leave TFS 2012 as it is?

Comment: The instructions for TFS 2013 are [here](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/From+Team+Foundation+Server+2013): you could try those so see if they also work for TFS2012 (although I'm not sure TFS2012 is still supported).

Comment: @duncanp: I went through this page, but I don't have executable files to put in the agents configuration. I run in SaaS mode.

Comment: @JeroenHeier: Because our organization are currently looking for this avenue, but are not ready yet to make the move. Our VSTS installation is a kind of bench test at the moment. All the new development is still made in TFS 2012.

Comment: @mxc do you mean you have an on-premise installation of TFS2012, and are trying to access an instance of SonarQube hosted on an Azure VM? If so, which machine is acting as your XAML build agent? That is the machine that would have the Scanner for MSBuild exe on it. You would set the sonar.host.url property to point to your SonarQube server (so unless the TFS XAML build agent and SonarQube instance are on the same Azure VM then you'll need to specify a URL other than localhost).

Comment: Ah I see. For your info, yes it's an on-premise TFS. I thought the analyzer were called on the SonarQube Azure server, but you are right, I can install the msbuild analyzer on our TFS agent and modify the config file to point to our azure server. Thank you very much!

Comment: FYI you won't be able to use v4 of the Scanner of the MSBuild as the support for XAML builds was inadvertently broken in that release (see https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARMSBRU-381). You'll need to install an earlier version of the scanner.